# Matplotilib: Divide figure in two sharing axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to divide a figure in two horizontally stacked parts sharing the same y axis. In particular, I would like the two parts to be attached, with no blank space between them.

To make an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, -y)
```

but I would like the two plots to be attached and to share the same y axis.

Comment: Take a look a [this broken axis demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html). The methods used there can be applied to your problem

Comment: This can be achieved by simply merging the left and right graphs and removing the ticks and borders. `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True);fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots');ax1.plot(x, y);ax2.plot(x, -y);fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0);ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False);
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', length=0)`

Comment: May I ask you how to plot bar charts in those subplots?

Comment: You can just change the two plots to ax.bar and set the data for the bar chart.